# GTM ecommerce after container container code on page

Tags: google-analytics, transactions, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

I want to use GTM to track eCommerce transactions. This is a test for client environments where the code might be placed **after** the GTM code snippet which is why using `Dom Ready` as a trigger for the transaction tag is not reliable.

This is my test code:

```
<body>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];</script>
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-M4RNT2"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
<div class="container">
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
dataLayer.push({
   'transactionId': '32698',
   'transactionAffiliation': 'Acme Clothing',
   'transactionTotal': 38.26,
   'transactionTax': 1.29,
   'transactionShipping': 5,
   'transactionProducts': [{
       'sku': 'DD44',
       'name': 'T-Shirt',
       'category': 'Apparel',
       'price': 11.99,
       'quantity': 1
   },{
       'sku': 'AA1243544',
       'name': 'Socks',
       'category': 'Apparel',
       'price': 9.99,
       'quantity': 2
   }]
});
</script>
</body>
```

As you can see the eCommerce code is taken straight from the Google documentation [here](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en).

I made sure that the pageview tag I'm firing works and I can see myself on the realtime view.

The issue is that no matter what I do to trigger the transaction tag, no eCommerce transactions are shown in Google Analytics.

Here is what I've tried:

- Using `'event': 'eCommerce'` right after the transaction products or in a separate script tag after the transaction code push and then using that event as a trigger
- I've created a dataLayer variable in GTM that references `transactionId` and defaults it to `false` and then using event `gtm.dom` as a trigger with a filter for `transactionId does not equal false`

The frustrating part is that I have the GTM preview window open and it looks perfectly like it should work.

- In attempt 1 above it shows a sequence of pageview, message, eCommerce DOM ready, page load where the dataLayer after message is correctly filled with transaction data and the eCommerce tag firing on the eCommerce event (i.e. data is in the dataLayer for sure.
- In attempt 2 the dataLayer after `Message` is filled with transaction data and the eCommerce tag is fired on the `DOM Ready` event.

This has been going on for days now so it isn't a case of "the data hasn't shown up in GA **yet**". I am using the right UA tag since both tags reference the sasme onstant GTM variable and since I see myself in realtime the pageview tag uses the right UA and therefore so does the transaction tag. And yes eCommerce is obviously enabled in the view settings.

Answer (score 4):

Simply pushing the transaction data to the data layer will not trigger the tracking to work. You need an action such as a pageview to pick up the transaction data and send it.

If you are unable to add the data layer before the GTM snippet, my recommendation would be the following:

- Convert your code to be in the Enhanced Ecommerce format (provided below)
- Add a custom event, in this case it is named `trackTrans`.
- Add an event tag in GTM, labeled similar to `Send Transaction`. You can specify whatever values you'd like the for the event category/action/label.
- In the event tag go to `more settings` > `Ecommerce Features`, enable `Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Feature` and `Use data layer`
- Setting the trigger to be a `Custom Event` and specify `trackTrans` for the value
- In your view settings make sure to enbable enhanced ecommerce tracking

  ```
  dataLayer.push({
     'ecommerce': {
       'purchase': {
         'actionField': {
           'id': 'T12345',                         // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
           'affiliation': 'Online Store',
           'revenue': '35.43',                     // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
           'tax':'4.90',
           'shipping': '5.99',
           'coupon': 'SUMMER_SALE'
         },
         'products': [{                            // List of productFieldObjects.
           'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',     // Name or ID is required.
           'id': '12345',
           'price': '15.25',
           'brand': 'Google',
           'category': 'Apparel',
           'variant': 'Gray',
           'quantity': 1,
           'coupon': ''         
         }]
       }
    },
    'event' : 'trackTrans'
  });
  ```

With what I have described above, the page will load then an event will fire and send the ecommerce transaction data with it.

Comment: It is meant trigger the GTM again to wire up the data layer again?
Does the page view count duplicate? thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per your reference to the Google documentation, you need to

> Place this code **above** the Google Tag Manager container snippet so that the data layer is ready when Google Tag Manager fires the Google Analytics tag asynchronously.

Comment: I am not sure this is relevant - the OP is adding to the dataLayer via a push and I can confirm from experience with clients that this works okay with the GA transaction tag as long as it is triggered after the push via a custom event.

Comment: @nyuen that is the point of this exercise though, to make eComm tracking more robust since often we as an agency have little control over where both the GTM container and the eCommerce  code gets dropped on a page. I have found a way though, posting it in an answer below.

Comment: When you use regilar analytics tag in addition to ecommerce tag the UA tag forces you to push GTM inclusion script to the first line of the BODY html tag so dataLayer for the ecommerce must be initialized there too. This is often veryinconvenient way to insert custom data to the layout area (content of your current page where you can insert any customdata freely will always be much later in the html code).

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to make it work. Ryan's answer was close but our experience with using event based triggers was spotty at best. I am now using the following setup that essentially guarantees transaction pickups by GTM unless the code is dynamically injected after page load via JS.

Here is how:

1. I created a `dataLayer Variable` which references `transactionId` and set its default to `false`
2. I created a trigger of type `Custom Event`, set the event to `gtm.dom` and a filter for the dataLayer variable I created to be **not equal** to `false`.

This ensures an actual transaction on the page overwrites the default value of false in that GTM variable and the `gtm.dom` trigger ensures that all code has loaded.

We have already tested this with clients on varying degrees of awfullness in terms of GTM implementations.